# Check if a variable contains a domain name in a set of TLDs

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable name which contains name of DNS record. I want to check for certain conditions, for example if it ends with `.com` or `.es`.

Right now I am using

```
name="test.com"

namecheck=`echo $name | grep -w  "^[A-Za-z]*..com"`
```

but it only checks the `com` and ignores the `.` also is it possible to check it against series of value stored in array like

```
domain=[ ".es" ".com" ".de"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `egrep`:

```
egrep -q "\.(com|es|de)$"
```

This will return 0 (true) if given input is ending with `.com` OR `.es` OR `.de`

**EDIT:** Using it with an array of allowed domains:

```
domain=( "es" "com" "de" )
str=$(printf "|%s" ${domain[@]})
str="${str:1}"

echo "abc.test.com"|egrep "\.(${str})$"
abc.test.com

echo "abc.test.org"|egrep "\.(${str})$"
```

Answer (score 6):

Pure `bash` implementation:

```
name=test.com
domains=(es com de)
for dom in ${domains[@]}; do
    [[ $name == *.$dom ]] && echo $name && break
done
```

Comment: After solving my problem with ugly `grep` hacks I just found out about the `[[ expr ]]` ability to compare against wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX shell compliant and super-fast:

```
case "$name" in *.de|*.com|*.es) echo "$name" or whatever ;; esac
```